# Is it possible to navigate to "next issue" within a project?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

Is there a command to navigate to a next problem in a whole project but in a file. It happens all the time that you have an error somewhere and you need to trace your project in a `Project View` to find it.

How cool would it be to navigate where you need just right away!

**Update:**
Not only compilation errors count, but also syntax.

Comment: Do you mean something like Ctrl+Alt+Down?

Comment: @maba sorry, Mac user :)

Comment: Ok, I am normally a Mac user too but my work laptop uses Windows. Check in `Navigate` what the shortcut is for `Next Message`.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't find `Next Message` under `Navigate` menu.

Comment: Can you do Shift+Cmd+A to get `Find Action`? If so then type `Next Message` and see if that one is found there.

Comment: If you first run `Analyze` -> `Inspect Code...` and choose `Whole project` you will see all problems in the whole project. After that you can use Ctrl+Alt+Down (or the equivalent on Mac) to go to next problem.

Comment: When you have compiled at least once the Messages window will be available. After that you can find `Next Message` in the `Navigate` menu. On Mac you use Alt+Cmd+Down (just checked on my Mac).

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Analyze"->"Inspect Code". It will shows all issues in the whole project.

Comment: The whole point is to navigate quickly to the problem area, running inspections is not a way to go :)

Answer (score 1):

`CTRL + F9` (Make Project). This will also automatically scroll to your first error in the project. It will give you a list of your errors and you can then use `CTRL + ALT + DOWN` to go through the errors.

Also once you fix them, you can do the shortcut again as it might reveal more (compilation) issues that were hidden by the first ones.